# Hibernate: Document is invalid: no grammar found

Tags: hibernate

When I instantiate Hibernate using the following code:

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

I got the following exceptions:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.,
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element
>   "hibernate-configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2014)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1931)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1910)
>         at com.soccer.system.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:23)
>         ... 1 more
>       Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.

I use the following `hibernate.cfg.xml` file with Hibernate 4.1.6:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<hibernate-configuration
    xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/K:\db</property>
        <property name="connection.username"></property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What can I do to eliminate this exception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the line

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
```

as the second line (after the xml version and before the `<hibernate-configuration>` tag. Then it should work.

Comment: Adding the `DOCTYPE` is not sufficient, I also had to remove all the attributes from the `hibernate-configuration` element. Find it strange that hibernate favors `DTD` over `XSD`. You might also update the the `DTD` url to use `"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"` instead of the old sourceforge URL.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this code and the problem will be resloved.

```
xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```