# hibernate invalid configuration exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to `Hibernate`. My `Hibernate` configuration file is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration
    xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration        hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">QADEER</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property  name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="org.test.Person"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have the following Person.java class:

```
package org.test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person 
{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package org.test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Person obj=new Person();
        obj.setId(1);
        obj.setName("qadeer");

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SessionFactory buildSessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = buildSessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(obj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

when i run the code it give me following excwption.....

```
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml Sep 13, 2013 10:34:32 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2070)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1966)
                at org.test.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25;  Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapp er.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3065)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2067)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate: Document is invalid: no grammar found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288516/hibernate-document-is-invalid-no-grammar-found)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Hibernate 4.x you should use the same DTD as 3.x:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
```

as you can see by this [bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6617), where the deprecation warning was removed.
Also the tutorials for 4.2 version use this, as you can see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html_single/files/hibernate-tutorials.zip).

Comment: after adding also, I am getting same problem

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly says `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25; Document is invalid: no grammar found. at`
which means that there is no `baseline (define structure of the xml)` to check your `xml` tags against.

You need to add the hibernate `DOCTYPE`, which is

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
```

Also check is your `xml` well formed, look for any unclosed tags, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is related to `hibernate.cfg.xml`. For hibernate 4.3.0 Final also should use dtd as shown below to resolve this error.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working after adding below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">