# Intellij: web app is fine at work but stops working at home (via VPN)

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

Apologies if the question doesn't make too much sense, I'm still quite junior with front end programming.

I have this company web application that uses gradle. I'm familiar with NPM/ReactJS/JS/etc but not so familiar with gradle. By using Intellij/springboot I can run the the application on localhost (I need to run two things, one is the 'engine' and another is the UI). I believe these are some kind of TOMCAT server which run on localhost 9000 and 9001. This works fine at work (i can access the UI on localhost), but both engine and UI stop working at home (when using a VPN to connect to company intranet).

The error seems quite long to post, but i think these should be the important parts:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)
2017-07-29 01:27:15 12948 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]


Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Would anyone be able to advise on how to fix this?

Given this only stops working away from work (i.e. at home via VPN), i assume that is the culprit somehow.

I noticed an intellij warning about a maven repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) which wasn't loading. I thought this was the problem. After some time, I managed to add proxy settings in the maven install section. The repository loaded fine, but I still get the error

======================

When connected to the company VPN i can connect to a virtual machine via remote desktop connection. And via this virtual machine, I can access the DB which the web application is using

Comment: Looks like a database connection problem. Your app is probably not able to connect to the DB. Can you try connecting to the db directly from a client?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23467010/575350

Comment: When connected to the company VPN i can connect to a virtual machine via remote desktop connection. And via this virtual machine, I can access the DB

Comment: Can anyone help me understand why location/VPN makes a difference?

Comment: When connected to the company VPN i can connect to a virtual machine via remote desktop connection. And via this virtual machine, I can access the DB which the web application is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution. In Windows Credentials (search for 'cred' in windows search), i hold my db server login details there. from googling, it seems there is a long standing issue that i don't quite understand, where if i use my laptop at home, the credentials will be deleted. I added them back, and it works now. Posting this in case someone else has the same issue i did. Thanks all for your help

Comment: I don't really understand what you've done. Did you use Credential in EmbeddedLdapProperties class or another? And how did you use it? thanks