# HibernateException:could not parse

Tags: java, hibernate

I got problem,could not parsing configuration hiberenate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE</property>
<property name="connection.username">system</property>
<property name="connection.password">system</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping calss="com.jlcindia.hibernate/Customer"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the exception...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.jlcindia.hibernate.AHLab2Client.main(AHLab2Client.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: problem parsing
configurationhibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1291)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1230)
at com.jlcindia.hibernate.AHibernateUtil.<clinit>(AHibernateUtil.java:15)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1287)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 25; Document
is invalid: no grammar found.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
atorg.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.
scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.impl.
XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:334)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1286)
... 3 more
```

I checked my DB and all the tag here but i am also not able to solve it. plese help me.

Comment: I'm going to be rude, so I apologize in advance. The problem is that you cannot read. You cannot read the error message that comes out of that, which somewhere says `invalid attribute calss`... because you misspelled the word class.

Comment: ok,i done it, than also i am getting problem

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288516/hibernate-document-is-invalid-no-grammar-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace is stating that the doctype header is missing - add the line

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
```

at the start of the XML configuration file

There is an additional `/` which is terminating the tag early also a "class" typo both in the `mapping` tag . Replace

```
<mapping calss="com.jlcindia.hibernate/Customer"/>
```

with

```
<mapping class="com.jlcindia.hibernate.Customer"/>
```

Comment: we can end the mapping tag like this or not. i think its correct.

Comment: Did you try adding the header?

Comment: after adding doctype header tahn...ths exception coming...        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:752)
 at com.jlcindia.hibernate.AHibernateUtil.<clinit>(AHibernateUtil.java:17)
 at com.jlcindia.hibernate.AHLab2Client.main(AHLab2Client.java:15)

Comment: That's a different issue (related to the version of the jars that you're using) and deserves its own question. The parser _appears_ to be parsing the config file successfully now

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Resource:com.jlcindia.hibernate/hibernate.hbm.xml not found          at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource (Configuration.java:442) at org. hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1381)at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory (Configuration.java:1353 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1335)at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1302)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes with this line

```
<mapping calss="com.jlcindia.hibernate/Customer"/>
```

1. `class` is mis-spelled as `calss`.
2. `com.jlcindia.hibernate/Customer` should have been `com.jlcindia.hibernate.Customer` - I'm assuming that this is the entity class.

After correcting the 2 mistakes, that line should something like this

```
<mapping class="com.jlcindia.hibernate.Customer" />
```

**Side Note:** A good IDE would have highlighted the error in the `xml` file then and there(with where exactly the error is). I suggest you use one(in case you're not using any).

Comment: i correct all tag now i also getting same exception . and it shows that ... lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 25; Document is invalid: no grammar found. it is not reaching end at <mapping class="com.jlcindia.hibernate.Customer"></mapping> .

Comment: This exception coming after adding Doctype header.                                                              Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;
 at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:752)
 at com.jlcindia.hibernate.AHibernateUtil.<clinit>(AHibernateUtil.java:17)
 at com.jlcindia.hibernate.AHLab2Client.main(AHLab2Client.java:15)