# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration in hibernate4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hibernate-4.x

I am stuck with hibernate configuration file exception, this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgresql</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="org.person.PersonModel"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using hibernate-core-4.1.12.Final.jar, I am getting the following exception:

```
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2022)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1939)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1918)
    at org.person.PersonPersistance.main(PersonPersistance.java:14)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 25; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
```

By seeing the respective exception I came to know that I have some mistake in my configuration file. I want to know what mistake I have done in my configuration file.

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12294976/95033 ?

Comment: thanks for your info, i got the this exception after modifying   WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 2):

When I wrote same program in Eclipse Luno, it has got execute. Try this and see.

Add this before `<hibernate-configuration>` tag:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: Please provide some more information about why you think this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate 4.x you should use the same DTD as 3.x:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>

 <session-factory>
```