# How to resolve (Spring+Hibernate ) code error Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid mapping

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate

## mycomfig.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydata"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="1"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
         <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
            <value>com/info/Customer.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <!--<property name="configLocation"
            value="com/info/hibernate.cfg.xml">
        </property>-->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
         <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="hTemp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernetTemplate" autowire="constructor"/>
    <bean id="cdao" class="com.info.HibernateCustomerDAO"/>
</beans>
```

---

## Customer.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.info">
    <class name="Customer" table="mycustomer" lazy="false">
        <id name="cid" column="cid" type="int"/>
        <generator class="increment"/>
        <property name="cname"/>
        <property name="email"/>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.Long"/>
        <property name="city"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

## Error Message

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in
>   thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [myconfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid mapping  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at com.info.Lab48.main(Lab48.java:8) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid mapping   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:394)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:677)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2;
>   columnNumber: 19; Document is invalid: no grammar found.  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:228)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
>     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:334)  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:393)
>     ... 16 more

Comment: Please post the FULL stack trace as a code segment NOT as a comment as you did now...

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288516/hibernate-document-is-invalid-no-grammar-found